# Why is `<FilesMatch>` prefered over `<Files>` in Apache, when using regular expressions?

Tags: apache

The [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files) say:

> Regular expressions can also be used, with the addition of the `~` character. For example:
>
> ```
> <Files ~ "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
> ```
>
> would match most common Internet graphics formats. `<FilesMatch>` is
>   preferred, however.

But I don't understand why it's preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially both will do the same. Often when such situations occur it's an issue of styling/readability. For example if someone isn't familiar with Apache's config `Files` will read as 'this will match given filenames, as in Unix filenames', `FilesMatch` however is more reader friendly when used wih regex. The match part will give away that matchers as in regex matchers are involved, opposed to the `~` with `Files`.

Be sure to pick one for regex, not both. Be consistent, this will ensure readability of your config file.

Comment: I Thought the ~ made the regex of Files relative the path of any nestled Drectory or Location that might wrap it where as FilesMatch was'nt

Answer (score 1):

There is no good reason and they do the same thing at runtime.

Directives with a *Match alternative are the consistent way used by Apache to have a regex-accepting flavor of an existing directive.

It is simply a configuration style/consistency issue.